# Forcing a mat-slide-toggle to be true with formControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, toggle, form-control

Is there a way to force the mat-slide-toggle to be true under a condition. (If someone tries to make it false, either it doesnt budge, or it goes back to true instantly).
Something functionally equivalent to `forcedTrue="someCondtion"` in

```
<mat-slide-toggle
    formControlName="compression"
    class="margin-top"
    forcedTrue="someCondtion">
    {{'compression' | translate}}
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: why not set its "checked" value if your condition is met and disable ist, while it is met?

Comment: @Chund yes that works, silly of me to not think of that. Thanks.

Comment: no problem at all, we all have that kind of mental blockade every once in a while :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [checked]="true" [disabled]="true"

```
   <mat-slide-toggle
    formControlName="compression"
    class="margin-top"
    [checked]="true"
    [disabled]="true">
    {{'compression' | translate}}
  </mat-slide-toggle>
```